# type of the link(url)

Tags: flutter, dart, http

i want to know what is the type of the link i have i use http before but sometimes there is some links that doesn't have Content Type like this video link
Headers: {date: Thu, 22 Feb 2024 12:43:52 GMT, transfer-encoding: chunked, server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0, allow: GET}

```
  try {
    final uri = Uri.parse(downloadLink); // Convert string to Uri object
    final response = await http.head(uri);
    final headers = response.headers;
    return headers['content-type'];
    }    catch (e) {
    print('Error fetching content type: $e');
    return null;
    }
```

i used this code before but it doesnt work for every link(url)
is there any way or package to use ?

Comment: I assume it's a problem with the server rather than the `http` package. Did you check the header using e.g. curl?

Comment: like how to use header using e.g. curl 
can u make an example ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


Future<String?> fetchContentType(String downloadLink) async {
  try {
    final response = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(downloadLink));
    final httpResponse = await response.close();
    final contentType = httpResponse.headers.contentType?.toString();
    return contentType;
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error fetching content type: $e');
    return null;
  }
}
```

You can try this alternative approach wherein http GET request is performed first followed by parsing the content type from the response.